# What are some useful tests to do in selenium?

Tags: java, unit-testing, selenium, intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver

I'm using intelliJ to write some java tests for an online client data management site. I'm just experimenting at the moment. I've managed to be able to check elements on a page and click links. I was just interested if anyone knows any other useful tests that I could run on the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that the best tests to do in selenium are the ones that automate interactivity. If it is a pretty standard, data only site, you can just check to make sure the site has working links and so on (there are other tools that do this online, so you may be wasting time using selenium for something so basic).

If you have an interactive web application, that's where selenium can help you to test various functionality. 
I.e.

- you can have a test case to check for logging in and logging out,
  give the user different levels of access and see what they can see on
  their screen.
- Can they see administrative links?
- What elements can
  they see on certain pages?
- Can they view other users on the system
  (if this is an intranet, this might be useful)?
- Can they edit these
  fields (they shouldn't be able to, unless they are admin).
- What
  happens when an admin edits a field?
- Does the site retrieve the new
  value from the database or is the old value still persistant from the
  database or cookies?
- And so on...

There are a whole lot of tests to perform and they are very dependent on what you are programming and what you need to test. Instead of looking for selenium only tests, I would recommend you find a good book on best practices in software testing and try and learn the mindset instead of specific use cases.

Comment: +1 for emphasising that Selenium tests are part of a broad test approach

Answer (score 1):

Test I'm using:

- login (form submission in general)
- data retrieval and validation against db
- accessing random links/sites and checking for errors